# Leaflet spin with typescript

Tags: typescript, module, leaflet, amd, commonjs

I'm trying to use [leaflet spin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin) with an ionic 3 - Angular project. I added the plugin and spin.js as mentioned in the readme but I was getting the error [map.spin is not a function](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin/issues/27). Going through their documentation they have mentioned that the plugin can be loaded via AMD/CommonJS. How can I use such plugins with typescript?